# Building a menu similar to stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to customise my asp.net menu similar to the stackoverflow menu above. Can anyone please provide the CSS style or suggest how to do this?

Thanks.
James.

Comment: Your browser already has the CSS, just press F12 in IE or Chrome and use the developer console tools to see both the HTML and the CSS used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this
[Basic pills](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

I hope this will be a great start for you .Try responsive design too.
Happy coding